Is it possible for a fuse to blow at extremely low temperatures?
From what I understand, when a circuit is overloaded, the fuse heats up and eventually blows. This means that the fuse blowing is typically caused by high temperatures resulting from the overload.
Is it possible for a fuse to blow at extremely low temperatures, such as in a liquid nitrogen environment?

Question is too coarse - there are many different fuse types. A simple fuse that melts a metal wire will work - but significantly above its ratings for normal environments.

There are re-rating curves for fuses (for a random example, see page two of: https://m.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=990f7193-d9a2-48e4-b760-2b43514249cf&filename=littelfuse_fuse_215_datasheet.pdf) but I would contact the manufacturer if your application lies outside of the ranges shown in the curve for the particular fuse you are using. Odd things can happen at cryogenic temperatures and of course submersion in boiling liquid nitrogen will have different heat transfer characteristics than free air etc.

The fuse wire may become brittle at low temperatures and fracture due to the thermal transient when the device is turned on.

If the temperature is extremely low and the heat transfer is very low, the fuse may blow. But at medium temperature and an extremely high heat transfer the fuse may not blow. A fuse immersed in a high speed flow of liquid nitrogen may behave very different to the same type of fuse at the temperature of liquid nitrogen but within gaseous nitrogen of very low pressure.

@vir how do you apply the re-rating factor for a particular temperature?  Do you modify the current or the time coordinates of the original fuse curve?

I just use the re-rating curve to shift the time-current curves left or right.

It is very unlikely that the fuse wire is made of a high temperature (liquid nitrogen) superconducting material

@vir thank you.  So, for example, if the percent rating value was 105% you would multiply the current coordinates by 1.05, leaving the time coordinates as-is.  Correct?  Thanks again

Are you asking about if it will still blow in an overload condition, or are you asking if extremely low temperatures will themselves cause the fuse to blow even without any overload?

@relayman357 yes, but it's important to remember that those curves are averages of the trip characteristics and that the tolerances might be themselves larger than the change introduced by a temperature difference.

@vir understood, thank you.

The fuse should blow in liquid N2, though at a higher current than the manufacturer's curves would typically cover. The fuse element will be isolated by something like the Leidenfrost effect where the element is surrounded by a nitrogen bubble, so it's not as bad as actual contact with liquid N2. Depending on the fuse construction probably the element can't contact external liquid anyway.
Strange things can happen at cryogenic temperatures, but liquid N2 at normal atmospheric pressure is relatively toasty at 77K and usually most materials behave in a way that's consistent with behavior nearer room temperature. For example, the fuse element resistance will be considerably less than a room temperature until it warms up. As you approach 0K (say 10K to near liquid He temperatures 4.2K and below) things can get weirder.
That's my prediction anyway for a normal fuse, it's easy enough to profile with a dewar (or a picnic cooler) and some LN2. Something like a 'PTC' resettable fuse may indeed do something strange due to the behavior of the polymer.

You'll only get a Leidenfrost bubble during initial cooldown and if the fuse is dissipating enough heat to make/maintain one.  But with the reduced resistance it won't be much of a heater.  So the behaviour will gain non-linearities that aren't present at room temp.

Yes, even at low enough temperatures, and for applicable alloys where superconduction occurs: eventually, magnetic field at the superconductor surface exceeds the critical field, and breakdown follows.
At typical critical current densities, Joule heating in most any amount of wire will cause rapid heating; in superconductor magnets, this is tempered by embedding the SC filaments in a copper matrix, which slows the release of energy (current spreads out from the SC filaments into the bulk, at a rate determined by skin effect), and is very thermally conductive itself.  You could make a fuse without such matrix and simply allow the filament to vaporize.  (The ensuing discharge, within a cryostat, will have to be managed, though: helium has a rather low ionization energy, or thermionic emission and sputtering will maintain an arc in vacuum.)
Needless to say, the breaking current for a superconductor will be wildly different from room temperature!
A more consistent current rating can be had by choosing an alloy with small RRR (residual resistance ratio), i.e. electron flow through the material is frustrated even in the absence of thermal scattering, by the presence of random impurities, grain boundaries, etc..  Likewise, there are materials which do not superconduct even at absolute zero.  A material fitting both of these criteria, will have a similar resistance and not exhibit any strange behavior at arbitrarily low temperatures.  Stainless steel might be a typical example.
There will still be a spread due to the higher temp rise before melting, which I don't think is going to be so easy to solve.  But ultimately, fuses are crude elements at best: they exist to protect the wiring, by being a small bit of wire that blows first, in a safe and controlled environment.  At least here on Earth, there are very few applications, I think, where any real power control and protection is needed within the cryostat, and that can't be managed by better design.  That is: it's a heck of a lot easier and cheaper to put in a little more effort to avoid creating those problems in the first place, than to do re-solve more basic (time consuming) problems like how to make a reliable fuse, while keeping the cryostat cold and clean in the process, etc..
Perhaps this changes say when considering industrialization of space, but likely semiconductor switches will be worth the effort; the cost of working in space, in general, making the expense of relatively large devices reasonable.  (That is, consider the ratings required to switch mains voltage: several kV when off, some 100s A when on, to handle both surge and fault conditions.)
Maybe that varies depending on where the semiconductors have to be sourced from; a zero-g fab would be itself quite the feat, but perhaps simpler yet effective devices can be fabbed locally (vacuum mechanical switch, etc.?), and are thus worth the challenge of evaluating cruder control methods in extreme environments.
But even this is something of a digression: the depth of distant space may be cold, but it doesn't take much power dissipation to raise a spacecraft's temperature well above room temp.  Temp of an unmanned craft or facility is something of a free variable; higher temperatures might be desirable to make radiation more effective (cooling of components relative to each other, and exterior surfaces to space), or lower temperatures to make electrical transmission easier (lower resistance); or anything depending on the choice of working fluids needed in a given process (you can go ahead and condense or vaporize most any room-temp gas or liquid you might need).
But needless to say -- unless you have something more obvious in mind that I've missed -- which is entirely possible -- I'm not sure what application that requires cryogenic temperatures wouldn't be better solved through other means than stock fuses (or is worth spending the engineering effort to redesign such components).

It is very unlikely that the fuse wire is made of a high temperature (liquid nitrogen) superconducting material. The question did not mention liquid helium, much more expensive than liquid nitrogen.

I'm fond of taking the "yes and" approach; if it's easy to answer the limiting case including down to absolute zero, why not :)

The working principle of a fuse is how fast the heat generated by resistive heating can transfer outwards.  The principal heat barrier is the confined radiation surface of the wire.  The radiation back from the fuse shell is comparatively irrelevant as the respective surface area is much larger.  And from the contacts it is irrelevant because heat transfer along the wire is too slow to affect the middle of the fuse significantly.
So the only really relevant problem occurs when the wire itself is at temperatures where its resistance (and thus the heat generated by a certain current) is significantly different (in particular lower since higher resistance will just bring the wire up to working temperature and thus working resistance), or when the integrity of the fuse is breached and heat or electricity conducting liquids/gasses make it inside.  Or when the wire becomes brittle and will just shatter instead of melting due to mechanical strain.
In short: it should be reasonably simple to create fuses that work at low temperatures, but if your fuse is not specified for it, you cannot depend on it.
